# Orthogonal differentiable family of curves

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves, curvature

This problem is out of section 4-4 in M. do Carmos' *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*:

> We say that a set of regular curves on a surface $S$ is a differentiable family of curves on $S$ if the tangent lines to the curves of the set make up a differentiable field of directions. Assume that a surface $S$ admits two differentiable orthogonal families of geodesics. Prove that the Gaussian curvature of $S$ is zero.

As a tip, he says:

> Parametrize a neighborhood of $p\in S$ in such a way that the two families of
>   geodesics are coordinate curves (Corollary 1, Sec. 3-4). Show that this implies
>   that $F = 0, E_v = 0 = G_u$. Make a change of parameters to obtain that $\bar{F} = 0, \bar{E} = \bar{G} = 1$.

I know that for every $p\in S$ we can find a neighbourhood $U\subset S$ of $p$ and a parametrization $X:I\times J\to U$ such that the coordinate curves $\alpha_{v_0}(u)=X(u,v_0)$ belong to one family and $\beta_{u_0}(v)=X(u_0, v)$ belong to the other. That way,

$$F=<X_u,X_v>(u_0,v_0)=<\alpha'_{v_0}(u_0), \beta'_{u_0}(v_0)>=0$$

I also know that if I can prove that $E_v=G_u=0$, then I can use the formula for orthogonal parametrizations:

$$K=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}\left\{\left(\frac{G_u}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_u+\left(\frac{E_v}{\sqrt{EG}}\right)_v\right\}$$

to prove that $K=0$, but I don't know how to prove that. Besides, I don't see the need of changing parameters to get $\bar{E}=\bar{G}=1$. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: One way to do this is to look at the Christoffel symbols and the equations for geodesics once you're in a coordinate system with $F=0$.

Comment: Using the Christoffel symbols and using the fact that $F=0$, the problem of proving $E_v=G_u=0$ reduces to proving $\Gamma^1_{12}=\Gamma^2_{12}=0$. I can't see how this helps...

Comment: You have to write down what the differential equations become when the $u$- and $v$-curves are themselves the geodesics. What does that mean about the differential equations? Stop and think.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I'm trying to work with the differential equations now. I've concluded that the $u$-curves are geodesics $\Leftrightarrow \Gamma^1_{11}=\Gamma^2_{11}=0$ and that the $v$-curves are geodesics $\Leftrightarrow \Gamma^1_{22}=\Gamma^2_{22}=0$. Sorry, I still can't see where this goes.

Comment: I mean, if they are geodesics, I agree that this implies $\Gamma^1_{12}=\Gamma^2_{12}=0$, which implies $E_v=G_u=0$, as desired. But why would they be geodesics?

Comment: Because that's what doCarmo's hint says to do. These are the coordinate curves!

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you explain why the coordinate curves are geodesics? I really didn't understand

Comment: @MatheusManzatto: We're *choosing* local coordinates $(u,v)$ so that they *are* geodesics. We then look at the differential equations for geodesics to deduce that certain Christoffel symbols vanish and, then, that $E_v=G_u=0$. You can do the converse as well.

Comment: @TedShifrin (Corollary 1 - Sec 3.4) say: "Given two fields of directions $r$ and $r'$ in a open set $U \subset S$ such that at $p$ $\in$ $U$, $r(p) \neq r'(p)$, there exists a parametrization $X$ in a neighborhood of $p$ such that the coordinate curves of $X$ are the integral curves of $r$ and $r'$."  It's not obvious to me why $X(u,c^{te})$ and $X(c^{te}, v )$ are geodesics. Because they are only integral curves

Comment: Because doCarmo starts with two orthogonal families of geodesics in the first place. Use their tangent vector fields for that corollary!

Comment: @TedShifrin , sorry to insist on it, but if the fields $w_1 , w_2 : S \rightarrow TS$, are the fields that you suggest (the tangent vector fild of the two orthogonal families). We only know that $X_u (u, v)$ $\in$ $\mbox{span}(w_1(X(u,v) )$, and $X_v (u, v)$ $\in$ $\mbox{span}(w_2(X(u,v) )$. Wich imply $X_u (u,v) = \lambda(u,v)  w_1 (u,v) $ and $X_v (u,v) = \mu(u,v)  w_2 (u,v) $. I can't see why the coordinates curves must be geodesics. I think they can be curves that has same path of the geodesics but not with constant tangent norm.

Comment: Correct. We're talking about the curves as curves, not as parametric curves. Some authors call these pre-geodesics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to show that a surface which admits two orthogonal families of geodesic is isometric with a plane (i.e. the Gaussian curvature is zero) in three steps:

- we show the the coordinate lines are orthogonal
- we show that once parametrized the two families of geodesics by coordinate curves $E_v=0$ and $G_u=0$
- we use the fact that when $F=0$, $E_v=0$ and $G_u=0$ the Gaussian curvature is zero

**First step**

Consider two plane curves $\alpha(t)$ and  $\beta(t)$ in the domain of $X$, and let $\gamma(t)=X \circ \alpha$ and $\delta(t)=X \circ \beta$ be the corresponding curves on the regular surface S. Then at the point $p= X(\alpha(t_0))=X(\beta(t_0))$, the angle $\theta$ between the two curves is
\begin{equation}
\cos{\theta}= \frac{\gamma' \cdot \delta'}{|\gamma'||\delta'|}
\end{equation}
In the basis ${X_u,X_v}$ the above equation becomes
\begin{equation}
\cos{\theta}= \frac{X_u \cdot X_V}{|X_u||X_v|}= \frac{F}{E G}
\end{equation}
Thus, all the coordinate curves of a parametrization are orthogonal if and only if $F=0$ for all $(u,v)$ in the domain of $X$.

**Second step**

Given the metric tensor $f$ 
\begin{equation}
f=\sqrt{E(u,v)u'^{2}+2 u' v' F(u,v)+G(u,v) v'^{2}}
\end{equation}
we compute the following partial derivative:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{2 f} \big(u'^{2} E_u+2 u' v' F_u+v'^2 G_u \big)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u'}=\frac{1}{f} \big(u' E+v' F \big)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{2 f} \big(u'^{2} E_v+2 u' v' F_v+v'^2 G_v \big)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v'}=\frac{1}{f} \big(u' F+ v' G \big)
\end{equation}
where $E_x$, $F_x$, and $G_x$ are the derivative of $E$, $F$, and $G$ with respect to the coordinate x ={u,v}, while $u'$ and $v'$ are the derivative withy respect to the parameter $t$. On the curve $v=constant$, $u$ can be taken as a parameter, then the curve is $u=t$, $v=c$. We also have that $u'=1$ and $v'=0$. By substituting these values in the previous equations we have:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{E}} E_u
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u'}=\sqrt{E}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{E}} E_v
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v'}=\frac{F}{\sqrt{E}}
\end{equation}
According to the Euler-Lagrange theorem in the calculus of variations, the parametric equation $(u(t),v(t))$ that optimize the metric $f$ must satisfy the differential equations:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}-\frac{d}{dt} \big (\frac{\partial f}{\partial u'} \big)=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}-\frac{d}{dt} \big (\frac{\partial f}{\partial v'} \big)=0
\end{equation}
By substituting the above values, after some calculations we have that the curve $v= constant$ is a geodesic if
\begin{equation}
E (E_v- 2 F_u) + E_u F =0
\end{equation}
This condition is therefore necessary. Conversely if the above condition is satisfied, it is possible to prove that the curve $v= constant$ is a geodesic. We can now repeat the same computation for a curve $u=constant$. In this case, $u=constant$ is a geodesic if and only if
\begin{equation}
G (G_u- 2 F_v) + G_v F =0
\end{equation}

**Third step**

We can then conclude that for orthogonal parametrizations two families of geodesics are coordinate curvesmusrt satisfy the conditions $F=0$, $E_v=0$, and $G_u=0$. Thus the metric tensor becomes:
\begin{equation}
f=\sqrt{E(u)u'^{2}+G(v) v'^{2}}
\end{equation}
In the situation where one considers an orthogonal parametrization of a neighborhood of a surface, the Gaussian curvature can be written as
\begin{equation}
K=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{E G}} \big[\frac{\partial }{\partial u} \big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{E}} \frac{\partial \sqrt{G}}{\partial u} \big)+\frac{\partial }{\partial v}\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{G}} \frac{\partial \sqrt{E}}{\partial v} \big)\big]
\end{equation}
Since $E=E(u)$ and $G=G(v)$, we have that the Gaussian curvature is zero. The formula I used for the Gaussian curvature can be derived by the usual definition of the Gaussian curvature computed as the radio of the determinants of the second and first fundamental form, by writing the determinal of the second fundamental form by using the triple product. The computation is quite long.