# If a surface $S$ admits two differentiable orthogonal families of geodesics $\Rightarrow$ The Gaussian curvature of $S$ is zero.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, geodesic

This question was previously posted in [Orthogonal differentiable family of curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275408/orthogonal-differentiable-family-of-curves?noredirect=1) . But I'm facing unsolved issues.

I'm still interested in solve the following exercise:

> **QUESTION:** We say that a set of regular curves on a surface $S$ is a differentiable family of curves on $S$ if the tangent lines to the curves of the set make up a differentiable field of directions. Assume that a surface $S$ admits two differentiable orthogonal families of geodesics. Prove that the Gaussian curvature of $S$ is zero.

where a differentiable field of directions is:

> **Definition:** A field of direction $r$ in a open $U \cap S$ is a correspondence which assigns to each $p$ $\in$ $U\cap S$ a line $r(p)$ in $T_pS$ passing through $p$. $r$ is said to be diferentiable at $p$ $\in$ $U \cap S$ if there exists a nonzero differentiable vector field $w$, defined in a neighborhood $V\cap S$ $\subset$ $U \cap S$ of $p$, such that for each $q$ $\in$ $V\cap S$, $w(q) \neq 0$ is a basis of $r(q)$; $r$ is diferentiable in $U\cap S$ if it is differentiable for every $p$ $\in$ $U$.

At the end of the book, Manfredo give us the following hint

> **Manfredo's Hint**: Parametrize a neighborhood of $p\in S$ in such a way that the two families of geodesics are coordinate curves (Corollary 1, Sec. 3-4). Show that this implies that $F=0$, $E_v=0, $ $G_u = 0$. Make a change of parameters to obtain that $\bar{F} = 0$, $\bar{E} = \bar{G} =1$.

where Corollary 1, Sec.3-4 is:

> **Corollary 1. (Sec.3-4):** Given two fields of directions $r$ and $r'$ in an open set $U \subset S$ such that at $p$ $\in$ $U$, $r(p) \neq r'(p)$, there exists a parametrization $x$ in a neighborhood of $p$ such that the coordinate curves of $x$ are the integral curves of $r$ and $r'$.

---

And now my problem appears.

Let $\tau_1$ be the field of directions associated to the first family, and $\tau_2$ be the field of directions associated to the second family (note that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are orthogonal).

I really don't understand why when we apply the Corollary 1 (Sec. 3-4), on the fields of directions $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, we end up getting a chart $x: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow W \cap S$, in such a way that the coordinate curves, $x(u, c^{te})$ and  $x(c^{te},v)$, are the two families of geodesics.

From what I know, when the coordinate curves are the integral curves of 
 fields of directions $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, we can only conclude that $x_u(u, c^{te})$ is l.d with the direction  $\tau_1(x(u, c^{te}))$ and  $x_v(c^{te},v)$ is l.d. with the direction $\tau_2(x(c^{te}, v))$.

GI can't see any reason for these coordinate curves to solve the geodesic's differential equation. In the best case scenario I was only able to conclude that the coordinate curves have the same path of a geodesic (which implies nothing).

Does anyone know how I outline this problem and solve the exercise?

Comment: First of all, I think that the first $W$ in the definition of field of direction should be a $V$, and that the  line $r(p)$ should pass by $0$, not $p$. Then I find this notion of field of direction very misleading. It seems equivalent to the notion of non-vanishing vector fields. I think it's better to work with nonvanishing vector fields.

Comment: Then let me denote by $(\gamma^{s})_s$ the first family of curves, and by $t$ the entry variable of $\gamma^{s}$. Denote by $(\tilde{\gamma}^a)_a$ the second family of curves and by $b$ the entry variable of $\gamma^{b}$. Couldn't you take for $\tau_{1}$ the vector field $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} b}\gamma^{a}$?

Comment: About your first question, the deffinition is wrong I will fix it. I need change $W$ for $U$ (I copied Manfredo's definition).  The line $r(p)$ pass by $p$ because Manfredo treats $T_p S$ as an affine space. But you can think in $T_p S$ using the usual definition, in this exercise doesn't change anything, but using the "usual" deffinition of Tangent Space, as you said, $r(p)$ should pass by $0$.

Comment: About the second question, we can't take the field $\tau_1$ as being $\frac{d}{db} \gamma^a$, because we don't know if this is a continuous field. We only know, by the definition of  field of directions, that exists a function $\lambda: V \cap S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that the field $\lambda(p) \frac{d}{db} \gamma^a (p)$ is differentiable.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know Manfredo's formalism, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I recently answer a very similar question on this site. If my answer on "Orthogonal differentiable family of curves" posted by AguirreK is not helpfull for you, please let me know.

Comment: I know you cannot use Gauss-Bonnet at this point, but this is so worth noticing: if you have a geodesic square $T$ with 90 degrees on each vertex, then Gauss-Bonnet gives:
$$\int\int_T \kappa~ dA=0.$$
Now you have a contradiction, since if you have a point where the curvature is non-zero, you can take a very small square around the point so that the curvature keeps its sign inside the square.

Comment: @Llohann Yes! Gauss-Bonnet solves the problem in a much simpler way.